# convert list of integers to list of two's complement bit representation using multiple cores

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, multiprocessing, bit

I've got a list with approx. 50 mio elements. Each element is a 32bit integer value representing 32 pixel of an optical line sensor. For further processing of the data, I need the two's complements binary representation of every integer value. This should give me a list of approx. 50 mio * 32 elements (1.5 billion) containing either 1 or 0.

I currently solve the problem straightforward by number crunching using a single core. However it is a bit time consuming. A normal file would take something around 300s until I can proceed.

For conversion of the integer value to the bit representation I use the following code (source: http://michaelwhatcott.com/a-few-bits-of-python/)

```
def bits(number, size_in_bits = 32):
    if number < 0:
        return compliment(bin(abs(number) - 1)[2:]).rjust(size_in_bits, '1')
    else:
        return bin(number)[2:].rjust(size_in_bits, '0')


def compliment(value):
    return ''.join(COMPLEMENT[x] for x in value)

COMPLEMENT = {'1': '0', '0': '1'}
```

The actual list is then derived by the following mapping:

```
import numpy as np    
mystring = "".join(map(bits, myrawdata))
myrawdata = np.fromstring(mystring, dtype = np.uint8, count = -1)
```

It works like expected with only on flaw of resulting in 48s and 49s instead of 0s and 1s as a result of the uint8-type. But I can work with that.

**Now comes the question**: How can I accelerate this by using multiple cores. I have tried so far using the map-function of the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) module of python. However, the performance is always slower than the single core mapping. I used the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(processes=3) as pool:         # start 3 worker processes (4-core system)    
    mystring = "".join(pool.map(bits, data))
```

This is usually 50% slower than the built-in single core map-function of python.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
u8s = myrawdata.view(np.uint8) # no copy, just change "shape"
comp = -u8s # or do you want np.invert(u8s) ?
bits = np.unpackbits(comp)
```

Now you have an array of `0`s and `1`s, of type `uint8`.

I think if you try the above solution you will no longer hope for a multi-threaded one, as it should be very fast already (under 4 seconds for 50 MM random integers on my machine).

Comment: Nice idea, already fumbled with np.unpackbits, but hadn't used the view-command. Unfortunatly, the view-command gives me the wrong order of the 8bit values. E.g., the number 100000 gets converted to the sequence 160, 134,   1,   0. It has to be 0, 1, 134, 160 to be equal to bin(100000). Surprisingly, as my integers are negative like -100000 unpackbits brings the correct bit sequence after manually sorting the values. I just have to find a quick sorting or reorder-algorithm.

Comment: Well, numpy.fliplr did the trick. And it's awesome fast. 4s for 38 mio elements vs. 220s with my mapping each element

Comment: I was just about to suggest `myrawdata.byteswap().view(np.uint8)` to replace my first line.  If `fliplr` does what you want then great, but perhaps the endian swapping operation is more clear?  Up to you!  See here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html  If I understand it, `fliplr` will reverse your entire array, whereas `byteswap()` will reverse the bytes of each integer, so it just depends whether you want the final answer reading "forward" or not.  Glad you've got it sorted!

Comment: thanks again! byteswap() is the nicer solution and it is slightly faster. well done ;)